# In-App-Purchase: correct handling of finishTransaction

Tags: objective-c, ios7, in-app-purchase

I've got the problem that some users pay the In-App-Purchase, but the app doesn't react on that; therefore my question is if the handling is correct this way:

```
- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions {
    for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in transactions) {
        switch (transaction.transactionState) {
            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchasing:
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:
                [self handlePurchase]; // seems like this isn't called sometimes

                // Remove the transaction from the payment queue.
                [queue finishTransaction:transaction];
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:
                // Remove the transaction from the payment queue.
                [queue finishTransaction:transaction];

                [self handleCancel];
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:
                [self handlePurchase]; // or this isn't called someimtes

                // Remove the transaction from the payment queue.
                [queue finishTransaction:transaction];
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Is the queue-handling correct this way? What does the `finishTransaction` do exactly? Should it only be called in the success-case?

Comment: Yes, you must call `finishTransaction` in every case. - Did you remember to make this object the observer for payments? What is your evidence that there's a problem? You're not testing on the Simulator, are you? That doesn't work...

Comment: From SKPaymentQueue.h: // Asynchronous.  Remove a finished (i.e. failed or completed) transaction from the queue.  Attempting to finish a purchasing transaction will throw an exception. --- So you are correct not to call it for the purchasing transaction. Your switch statement should be OK.